# python selenium xpath/css selector

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, xpath

I am trying to select for a particular information using xpath or css selector. But I keep on getting error messages. Can someone help with seeing what's wrong here?

[image: html]

This is part of my code

```
output = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class_= 'sku']")
print(output)
```

---

Using the modifications give below, I am obtaining this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sa.py", line 25, in <module>
    output = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@cl
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webd
   return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpa
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webd
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webd
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webd
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktra
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
td[@class=\'sku\']/p"}' ; Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_
ver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:9
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file://
ecode.com/components/driver_component.js:9479)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h
er@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:1
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (f
@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:114
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///
code.com/components/command_processor.js:11402)
```

---

This is the code that I have written:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/united-states.html"
#cas = "1300746-79-5"
cas = "100-44-7"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("Query")
inputElement.send_keys(cas)
inputElement.submit()

pricing_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.priceValue a")
pricing_link.click()

output = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='sku']/p") 
print(output)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the discussion with OP and alecxe, this is a timing issue, where you need to use [WebDriverWait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) to wait for table loading.

```
# XPath to select <p> inside <td> with class name 'sku'
outputs_by_xpath = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    lambda driver : driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[@class='sku']/p")
)

# or CSS selector
outputs_by_css = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    lambda driver : driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td.sku > p")
)

for output in outputs_by_xpath:
    print(output.text)

print("\n")

for output in outputs_by_css:
    print(output.text)
```

Output:

```
185558-50G
185558-250G
185558-1KG
185558-2KG

185558-50G
185558-250G
185558-1KG
185558-2KG
```

Comment: Hi. For the xpath method, I am getting an error message. Please see my response to the above post. Thank you