# Python Selenium - Get everything and write to file

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

noob here who just managed to be actively refused by the remote server. Too many connection attempts I suspect.
..and really, I should not be trying to connect every time I want to try some new code, so that got me to this question:
**So, how can I grab everything off the page, and save it to file**...and then just load the file offline to search for the fields I need.

I was in the process of testing the below code when I was Refused so I don't know what works - there are probably typos below :/
Could anyone please offer any suggestions or improvements.

```
print ("Get CSS elements from page")
parent_elements_css = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("*")
driver.quit()

print ("Saving Parent_Elements to CSV")
with open('ReadingEggs_BookReviews_Dump.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write(parent_elements_css)

print ("Open CSV to Parents_Elements")
with open('ReadingEggs_BookReviews_Dump.csv', 'r') as file:
    parent_elements_css = file

print ("Find the children of the Parent")
# Print stuff to screen to quickly find the css_selector 'codes'
# A bit brute force ish 
for css in parent_elements_css:
    print (css.text)
child_elements_span     = parent_element.find_element_by_css_selector("span")
child_elements_class    = parent_element.find_element_by_css_selector("class")
child_elements_table    = parent_element.find_element_by_css_selector("table")
child_elements_tr       = parent_element.find_element_by_css_selector("tr")
child_elements_td       = parent_element.find_element_by_css_selector("td")
```

These other pages looked interesting:

[python selenium xpath/css selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687271/python-selenium-xpath-css-selector)

[Get all child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795198/get-all-child-elements)

[Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

[xpath-partial-match-tr-id-with-python-selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54899464/xpath-partial-match-tr-id-with-python-selenium) (ah cos I asked this one :D..but the answer by Sers is awesome)

My previous file save was using a dictionary and json...but I could not use it above because of this error: "TypeError: Object of type WebElement is not JSON serializable". I have not saved files before that.

Comment: Why not simple request HTML and save it?

Comment: You are looking Save HTML Source Code into File ?

Comment: @ozlevka @ Govind Parashar. 
Ah, I did not know that was possible. I don't know anything about web pages.

How do I grab all the HTML from a page?

PS. I realised I could have scraped another page/site to test my code.. I will try again tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the html of the whole page via `driver.page_source`. You can then read from the html using beautiful soup so

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# navigate to page
html_doc = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
child_elements_span = soup.find_all('span')
child_elements_table = soup.find_all('table')
```

Here is a good documentation for parsing the html via BeautifulSoup https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/